# Set history dynamically without page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to update the url in the root component via following function:

```
const setHistory = ({ contractId, draftId, clauseClicked, category, history }) => {

  if (draftId) history.push(`${history.location.pathname}/draft/${draftId}`);

  if (clauseClicked) history.push(`${history.location.pathname}/clause/${clauseClicked.id}`);
...
};
```

The ideal url would be: `/legal-contract/${contractId}/draft/${draftId}/clause/${clauseClicked.id}/category/${category.id}` depending whether each of those parameters have values assigned to them.

But with my logic the url starts bubbling up with duplicates. What's the best way to set url without reloading page while remembering the history stack if possible?

Comment: I ended up doing that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the final path in a string variable and just use `history.push` once all variables have been checked.

```
const setHistory = ({
  contractId,
  draftId,
  clauseClicked,
  category,
  history
}) => {
  let newPath = `/legal-contract/${contractId}`;

  if (draftId) newPath += `/draft/${draftId}`;
  if (clauseClicked) newPath += `/clause/${clauseClicked.id}`;

  // ...

  history.push(newPath);
};
```